# Finding memories power dissipation

Tags: operational-amplifier, memory, power-dissipation, flash-memories

Can someone tell me how to calculate the power dissipation of digital ICs like NAND Flash, QSPI NOR Flash and microcontrollers?

Comment: Check the datasheet, there will be a power for idle, write and read cycles. You just need to know how long it spends doing each of those actions, and multiple and add up as requried.

Comment: sushmi Ram - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (b) Why did you tag this "operational-amplifier"? (c) Please [edit] your question and add your research so far, to avoid people wasting time telling you what you already know ([we expect people to do research](/help/how-to-ask) before posting here). (d) Why is your question more specific about the NOR flash (specifically QSPI) but very general about NAND flash & MCUs? (e) Please add context. Why are you asking? Thanks.

Comment: @Puffafish - Hi, Thanks for trying to help, however your comment is attempting to answer (at least part of) the OP's question, which is not one of the [few allowed uses of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Personally I don't think there's enough detail in the question to be confident what sort of answer the OP expects, especially given that MCUs are in the list and add their own complexity, which is why I asked the OP for more details. But, irrespective of that, if *you* have enough information to want to answer the question, please write an *answer* :) Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson: Puffafish's comment isn't an answer -- it's pointing out that the premise of the question is false; i.e., the power dissipation **can't** be calculated.

Comment: @DaveTweed - "*it's pointing out that the premise of the question is false*" That isn't my interpretation, but we agree that the question cannot be answered as-is. I didn't want to appear to be dissuading others from posting answers if *they* think a question can be answered (even when I don't). If your interpretation is correct & the comment was effectively sarcasm / mocking (where people have to be *very* careful not to fall foul of the [Code of Conduct](/conduct/abusive-behavior)), this would be a great example of why sarcasm on the site is a bad idea, as it may be misinterpreted :(